# Got error 'sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.' when insert data into table using sqlite3 python

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I tried to get the data from a url link and store it in a db file. When I converted the retrieved data to dataframe and inserted it into the table, I got an Error message saying 'sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 1-probably unsupported type.'

**Here is my code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import sqlite3
from pandas.io import sql
database_file = 'z5192421.db'

def if_table_exist(cnx,table_name):
    c = cnx.cursor()
    c.execute(f"SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND 
        name='{table_name}'")
    return c.fetchone()


def write_in_sqlite(dataframe, database_file, table_name):
    cnx = sqlite3.connect(database_file)
    c = cnx.cursor()

    if not if_table_exist(cnx, table_name):
        sql.to_sql(dataframe, name=table_name, con=cnx)
    else:
        for index, row in dataframe.iterrows():
            values = '('+','.join(['?']*len(dataframe.columns))+')'
            c.execute(f'INSERT INTO {table_name} VALUES {values}',
                      tuple(row.values))



def post():
    url = 'http://api.worldbank.org/v2/countries/all/indicators/' \
          'NY.GDP.MKTP.CD?date=2012:2017&format=json&per_page=1000'
    data = requests.get(url).json()[1]
    dfItem = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
    write_in_sqlite(dfItem,database_file, 'DATA')

post()
```

**And the traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/chenhao/PycharmProjects/untitled/9321/post_to_stack.py", **line 34, in <module>
    post()**

  File "/Users/chenhao/PycharmProjects/untitled/9321/post_to_stack.py", **line 32, in post
    write_in_sqlite(dfItem,database_file, 'DATA')**

  File "/Users/chenhao/PycharmProjects/untitled/9321/post_to_stack.py", **line 19, in write_in_sqlite
    sql.to_sql(dataframe, name=table_name, con=cnx,index = False)**

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", **line 512, in to_sql
    pandas_sql.to_sql(**

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", **line 1734, in to_sql
    table.insert(chunksize, method)**

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", **line 755, in insert
    exec_insert(conn, keys, chunk_iter)**

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", **line 1464, in _execute_insert
    conn.executemany(self.insert_statement(), data_list)**
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

Comment: It would help to give the full stacktrace including the line raising the error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it is now more clear. The error arises when you try to load the dataframe as a new SQLite table.

The problem is that the dataframe has object columns containing `dict` objects, which cannot be loaded directly into SQLite.

Possible workaround:

You can simply convert the offending `dict` values into mere strings prior to load the data into to database:

```
for i in ['country', 'indicator']:
    dfItem[i] = dfItem[i].apply(json.dumps)
```

This will change to `dict` object to their json representation, which will load fine as a TEXT field into a SQLite table.

But IMHO, you should better flatten the directory (beware the fields have `'id'` and `'value'` in both dicts) to directly store useable values. As I do not know how you intend to use the table, I cannot say more...